# How to show validation message on <TagsInput> react premade component on unique value

Tags: reactjs

I have an input tag component from `react-tagsinput` as follows:

```
const onTagChange = (tags) => {
  const noDuplicateTags = tags.filter((v, i) => tags.indexOf(v) === i);
  const duplicateEntered = tags.length !== noDuplicateTags.length;

  if (duplicateEntered) {
    onTagChange(tags);
    console.log('duplicate');
  }

  onTagChange(noDuplicateTags);
};

function TagContainer({
  tags,
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header>Meta:</Header>
      <TagsInput value={tags} onChange={onTagChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

TagContainer.propTypes = {
  tags: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
};

TagContainer.defaultProps = {
  tags: [],
};
```

export default TagContainer;
and the implementation on the `onTagChange` method which is passed as a prop to the `<TagContainer>` component in another component.

```
 export class Modal extends React.Component {
...
...
 onTagChange = (tags) => {
 this.props.onTagChange(tags);
}

...
...
render() {
 return(
   <TagContainer
        tags={tags}
        onTagChange={this.onTagChange}
      />
 );
}
}
```

**Problem:** `onlyUnique` prop in the `<TagsInput>` component is set to `true` to avoid duplicate entries. But I need to display an error message saying "duplicate values" as soon as user enters a duplicate value. How can this be done especially on the third party component.

Comment: Do you get any event through `onTagChange` when a duplicate tag is entered?

Comment: When duplicate tag is entered I can only see that the entered text gets removed and no other feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to handle dealing with duplicates in your component because you are getting no feedback from `<TagInput />` component.

At a higher level, I would do something like this

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showDuplicateError: false
    };
  }

  handleTagChange(tags) {
    const uniqueTags = removeDuplicates(tags);
    const duplicateEntered = tags.length !== uniqueTags.length;

    if (duplicateEntered) {
      this.showDuplicateError();
    }

    // add unique tags regardless, as multiple tags could've been entered
    const { onTagChange } = this.props;
    onTagChange(uniqueTags);
  }

  showDuplicateError() {
    this.setState({
      showDuplicateError: true
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { showDuplicateError } = this.state;
    const { tags } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        { showDuplicateError && <div>Duplicate entered</div>}
        <TagsInput value={ tags } onTagChange={ this.handleTagChange } />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am little confused. Should this be done completely on the component which only deals with displaying the Tag input fields? Because in that component I do not have handleChange. I have that on a different component. Also my TagContainer component that renders TagInput component is a funtional component and stateless. So I can't do what you have suggested. Is it correct?

Comment: You can use a prop callback instead of using state if you wanted to.
I can update my answer a little bit to conform closer to your example.

Comment: This has worked but not sure how to display a message in a div on duplicate entry

Comment: Can you include the component you want the message displayed? In the most simple form, you can store fact a duplicate has been entered in the state. Then use something like this `{ duplicateEntered && <div>You entered a duplicate tag</div>} `

Comment: I have updated my code and posted the entire Tag container. The problem was the component is a stateless pure component. Now `onChange` method is show stackoverflow error because it is called within. Not sure how to dissect this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without state. You must be keeping state somewhere - where are your tags coming from? I would do this `onTagChange` function at the state level and pass down the props `tags` and `duplicateEntered`.

Comment: tags are coming from `Redux` state in the component where TagContainer component renders. I previously had the `onTagChange` on the other component, but since I would have to use this TagContainer component in multiple places, I thought it would be better to do it in its own component.

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid state here? For me, this would be a situate to use component state as it is UI state - should it be showing an error message.

Comment: No particular reason to avoid state. So you suggest to make this component a class component instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178117/discussion-between-shaz-and-cameron-downer).